# Non blocking Restful web service in spring using apache cxf

Tags: web-services, rest

I have a Restful webservice implemented using apache cxf which takes JSON as input to perform some business logic and returns a JSON output. But now i need to convert this to a webservice call that does not return anything (for example return void) so that the user does not wait for its response and continue.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async REST calls with JAX-RS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440432/async-rest-calls-with-jax-rs)